# How do I take a string literal and save it back to raw JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, string, vue.js

I want to be able to edit object values by putting the value and the "value" of a text input element > `JSON.stringify(txt, null, 2)` that part works fine.

After submitting that input I'm left with a string literal containing "/n" and "\" after all quotations marks. I've tried regex and `string.replace()` to try to remove those but nothing works, my output is always something like this:

```
 "publisher": "[{\"name\":[\"scripps re\"],\"url\":[\"url.com\"]}]",
```

I've also tried `JSON.parse(txt)` and it logs fine but the result still contains line breaks and backslashes.

### QUESTION:

Is there a way to take the edited text from an input element and convert that back to valid JSON with no string literal marks?

I'm using:

**VueJS**, **JS**.

I've tried to bind the value of the input field like this:

```
 inputVal = JSON.stringify(object[keyname])
```

that works fine.

### ISSUE:

Assigning the newly edited txt:

```
 Vue.set(object, keyname, newValue)
```

newValue always has `/n`'s and `\`'s

I've tried:

```
Vue.set(object, keyname, newValue.replace('/n'g,""))

Vue.set(object, keyname, JSON.parse(newValue))


{
  "publisher": "[{\"name\":[\"scripps re\"],\"url\":[\"url.com\"]}]",
  "license": {
  "text": "CC BY-NC 4.0",
  "url": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/",
  "description": "Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0 International"
}
```

How can I edit the value of `'license'` for example, using a textarea input and save back valid JSON?

Expected result should be (prettified or not, just no line break marks):

```
{
  "publisher": "[{"name":["scripps re"],"url":["url.com"]}]",
  "license": {
  "text": "CC BY-NC 4.0",
  "url": "http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/",
  "description": "Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0 International"
}
```

Comment: when you did newValue.replace('/n'g,"") didn't it remove the line endings?

Comment: No, nothing seems to work, I can't get right of them

Comment: When i am trying to get rid of somet string related spacing, I say:  `str.replace(/[\n\t\r]/ig, '');` in order to strip carriage returns, tabs, etc.

Comment: All of these should work but for some reason nothing works and the value always has /n and \ .   Maybe it's Vue doing that, IDK...

Comment: Is each property of publisher and license a text input, or is there one text input for the whole publisher property?

Comment: @CathyHa one text input for the whole value as a string.  I found the issue tho, and I've answered it below, the problem was somewhere else. Thank you for taking a look a this tho!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!

So I was doing a check to see the type of newdata to avoid using JSON.parse on a string and get an error.  The thing is that the result was always a string so all the answers here would've worked.  I changed it to check the first index of the string to check for objects or arrays. Now it works great because things are being handled appropriately.

Thank you all that responded, technically all your answers should've worked but the problem was that part of the coded was never being triggered.

```
  if (newdata.value[0]==="{" || newdata.value[0]==="[") {
                        Vue.set(self.meta,keyname.value,JSON.parse(newdata.value) )
                      }else{
                        Vue.set(self.meta,keyname.value,newdata.value)
                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex needs to be corrected -

```
Vue.set(object,keyname,newValue.replace('/ng',""))
```

```js
s = "[{\"name\":[\"scripps re\"],\"url\":[\"url.com\"]}]".replace('/ng', "");
console.log(s);
```

Also you can use `unescape()`

```js
console.log(unescape( "[\n {\n \"identifier\": [\n \"IDEN\"\n ],\n \"institute\": [\n \"fds\"\n ],\n \"agency\": [\n \"fds\"\n ]\n }\n]" ));
```

However, `docodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` is preferred over `unescape` by the latest(Aug, 2019) MDN documentation

Comment: "funder": "[\n  {\n    \"identifier\": [\n      \"IDEN\"\n    ],\n    \"institute\": [\n      \"fds\"\n    ],\n    \"agency\": [\n      \"fds\"\n    ]\n  }\n]"       Didn't work for me, just adds more space after the line breaks.

Comment: I can see it work here but for some reason with the actual code it doesn't work, result is the same.  also says unescape is not exactly deprecated but there's a warning about it. I'm gonna try to pinpoint issue further but thanks for the help, idk why it's not taking, seems like such a simple thing...

Comment: unescape is depricated. A little note will help future reviewers

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all whitespace characters using the `/s` character class in regex

e.g. something like this `$('textarea').value.replace(/\s/g, '')`

Comment: IDK why all replace methods and regex don't work, the value is still the same. I'm gonna try to see where it's happening, thank you for the help!

Comment: try this for examining and testing how your regex will work; https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you!! I will use that